# Foreground color not working for attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to combine image and text inside `UILabel`. To accomplish that I'm using this part of code:

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
attributedText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "test",
attributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor,
                value: UIColor.white,
                range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
```

Text has white foreground color, but unfortunately image is still in original color. Interestingly, when I change first line to this (whitespace inside initializer):

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")
```

then everything is working fine. But the problem is that whole text inside label has offset due to whitespace. How can I change image color without adding whitespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041458/how-to-set-color-of-templated-image-in-nstextattachment

Comment: Does it work if you use the method that works (with the whitespace) and then remove the whitespace from the String with `attributedText.deleteCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(0,1))`? Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44769610/1298835

Comment: No, after deleting first character the image has wrong color. I also don't think that question you mentioned is a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough. According to the related question it was a bug back in 2015. It may not have been fixed until now.. hope the workaround in my answer helps, or someone else knows a better method that doesn't require a third party framework.

Comment: can you tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287386/change-string-color-with-nsattributedstring

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL which answer? Because whole question you mentioned is about changing color in the same way I do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287444/6193340 this answer

Comment: @BHAVIKPANCHAL I don't see the difference between what I do. Furthermore this answer is not even using any image.

Comment: Interesting would it work if to use instead of that space a non-printable neutral character like this one: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm ???

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use graphics context to invert colors. I would probably have this as an extension on `UIImage`.

Sample swift code is as follows.

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)
        let imageFromCurrentContext = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return UIImage(cgImage: imageFromCurrentContext!.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation:.downMirrored)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That behavior seems to be a bug in UIKit. Alas I don't know of a solution, hopefully someone else does, but for now here's a workaround:

You can color the image before adding it as a text attachment. An easy way to do that is to use a third-party framework, e.g. this one: https://github.com/vilanovi/UIImage-Additions

Then instead of `image.withRenderingMode(...)` you can simply write:

```
attachment.image = image.add_tintedImage(with: .white, style: ADDImageTintStyleKeepingAlpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the bug in UIKit still persists, but to avoid the offset due to the space, you can use an empty string instead of the space.
Just do:

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\0")
```

instead of

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ")
```